# comma in the wrong place

Tags: php

I have this issue i am writing a array to a file but when i unset() some sub arrays it keeps the comma or when i add anther sub array to the end it add a comma.

eg:

```
$account_data = include('./*****/AccountData.php');

$account_data[$username]['Name']     = $name;
$account_data[$username]['Password'] = $password;
$account_data[$username]['RandID']   = $randid;
$account_data[$username]['PublicD']  = $publicdownload;
$account_data[$username]['Enabled']  = $enabled;
$account_data[$username]['Admin']    = $admin;

$configdata = "<?php\n\nreturn ".var_export($account_data, true)."; \n\n?>";

$file = fopen('./*****/AccountDataTest.php', 'w');
fwrite($file, $configdata);
fclose($file);
```

when i run that code to add a sun array i get this

```
<?php
return array (
    'Ryan' => array (
        'Name' => 'Ryan',
        'Password' => '',
        'RandID' => '',
        'PublicD' => 0,
        'Enabled' => 1,
        'Admin' => 0,
    ),
    'Chris' => array (
        'Name' => 'Christopher',
        'Password' => '',
        'RandID' => '',
        'PublicD' => 1,
        'Enabled' => 1,
        'Admin' => 1,
    ),
);
?>
```

as you can see it adds a comma and when i run my unset function the code for the AccountData.php file will look the same with out the Chris but it has the following comma at the end of Ryan.

I am not sure how I can fix this I have been googling with not much luck.

Comment: Check this http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-export.php#51078

Comment: About which comma exactly do you speak (please highlight it), because the array dump looks very good! Nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but you would probably save yourself a lot of headaches by using [serialize](http://us.php.net/serialize) and [unserialize](http://us.php.net/unserialize) to save your data in a file.

Comment: That is a good idea I am going to change my code to use serialize and unserialize thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this, but store the data in a variable first and run it through a simple regex to remove the extra comma at the very end and after 'Admin' => *

Regex Tutorial: http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php